# How to call native C library using late binding?

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have been searching for examples of loading a native C library and calling its methods using late binding. I've seen plenty of examples when loading a managed library but not a native C library.

The native C library defines the following:

```
#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport )

typedef void (*CALLBACK_T)(long, void *);

CALLBACK_T g_Callback=NULL;

DllExport BOOL GetVersion(char *szVersion)
{
   AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
   strcpy( szVersion, GetAppVersion());

   return TRUE;
}

DllExport void SetCallbackFunction(CALLBACK_T f)
{
   AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

   g_Callback = f;

   return;
}
```

How can I load the DLL using late binding and call the two methods?

thanks in advance.
LA

---

I should mention that I need to load the library and call these methods from a c# application.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one way to get function addresses in Windows: `GetProcAddress`. You have to import it yourself, then load whatever functions you want by name. It returns an `IntPtr`.

Once you have your `IntPtr`, convert it to a `GCHandle` with `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` and then get the delegate with the `GCHandle.Target` property. Once you have your delegate, call it like normal. Make sure you decorate your delegate properly though, it still has to match the calling conventions in your C code.

Comment: Or, if you already have a delegate type, [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261456.aspx)

Comment: Oh wow they added that! .NET 4.5.1 minimum so if that fits, go ahead and use it!

Comment: There's also a non-generic version in older framework versions that takes a pointer and a type, which AFAIK has been around for a while.

Comment: I think I'm making progress but I'm getting an exception that states that likely my delegate signature does not match that of the library method. How do I marshal the string that is returned in the method GetVersion(char *version). I tried the following:

    public delegate bool _GETDLLVERSION ( IntPtr ptr );
    public delegate bool _GETDLLVERSION ( StringBuilder sb );

Comment: @user3242337 AFAIK, You can 't use a `StringBuilder` with a `char*`, as one uses unicode and the other doesn't. Either change the `char*` to a `wchar_t*`, or use a `byte[]` on the C# side. This is assuming the `char*` is used to output a string.

Comment: Use a plain `string` and a `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=200)]` or whatever size you want.

Comment: I've also tried using byte[] but I keep getting a PInvokeStackInbalance exception and telling me that it is because the managed signature does not match the unmanaged signature. My delegate is public delegate bool _GETDLLVERSION (byte[] buf); I suspect I'm missing something simple but cant figure it out.

Comment: Stack imbalance most likely means you're using the wrong call mode, it should probably be stdcall.